# Rmarkdown: writing inline dplyr code if column names have spaces defined with backticks

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, backticks, inline-code

## Problem

My inline code chunk breaks when I `filter()` or `select()` a column name that has white space that I would normally define with backticks in dplyr.

## Example Data

````
    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    library(dplyr)
    library(knitr)
    library(lazyeval)

    df <- structure(list(1:3, 2:4), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

    df <- df %>% select(`a a`=a, `b b`=b)
    ```
````

## Inline code chunk

I'm trying something like `` `r df %>% filter(`a a` == 1) %>% select(`a a`) %>% as.numeric()` ``, but I get the following error:

```
    Error in base::parse(text = code, keep.source = FALSE) : <text>:2.0: unexpected end of input 1: df %>% filter( ^ Calls: <Anonymous> ... inline_exec -> withVisible -> eval -> parse_only -> <Anonymous>
```

...for pretty obvious reasons (the backticks end the inline code chunk).  I could rename the columns in a code chunk after the intext calculations (I'm formatting them for a table), but it would be frustrating to have to break it up.

## Costly `lazyeval` solution

This solves the problem `r df %>% filter_(interp(~ which_column == 1, which_column = as.name("a a"))) %>% select_(as.name("a a")) %>% as.numeric()`, but there has got to be a better way.

Comment: Can you use the escape operator for the back ticks?

Comment: Can you use just single or double ticks? `df %>% select('a a'=a, 'b b'=b)` works the same for me (at least on the console). The only time I find I *need* to use backticks is referencing (not using) "SPECIAL" functions such as ```%in%```.

Comment: Or, of course, you could just not do fancy computations inline. Define `res = df %>% filter(\`a a\` == 1) %>% select(\`a a\`) %>% as.numeric()` in your chunk/block and then `\`r res\`` it inline.

Comment: @r2evans thanks but single/double ticks don't work for me. I get Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not: * "a a"

Comment: @RyanMorton the escape operator isn't working for me

Comment: @Frank yes, true.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you are running things - here I provide an answer with respect to `knitr`.

There is no easy solution for this case, and the work-around of moving some code inside the chunks (as suggested in one of the comments) is probably the way to go.

For future reference and further insight, I'll still share the underlying problem and an alternative solution.

Note that `knitr` makes use of the following pattern for `inline.code` (given you are using Rmarkdown format):

```
knitr::all_patterns$md$inline.code
[1] "`r[ #]([^`]+)\\s*`"
```

Now the function `knitr:::parse_inline` matches this through a call to `stringr::str_match_all`, which will detect patterns of one or multiple non-backticks (`` [^`]+ ``), followed by zero or multiple space-class elements (`\\s*`), followed by a back-tick.

So it will end on the first backtick following `` `r ``, more or less no matter what. This makes some sense, since the lines of input are collapsed in `parse_inline` and there could actually be multiple inline-code statements and plain text containing back-ticks in the resulting string.

If you however *restrict yourself to some conventions*, you could modify the pattern to detect the end of inline code pieces differently. Below I am assuming that I always break onto a new line following a piece of inline code, so e.g. following your `setup` chunk I only have the following:

```
Hello there.

`r DF %>% filter(`a a` == 1) %>% select(`a a`) %>% as.numeric()`

This should read 1 above here.
```

Then I can knit in the following way, modifying the pattern to take everything until a backtick followed by a new-line break:

```
library(knitr)
opts_knit$set('verbose' = TRUE)
knit_patterns$set(all_patterns$md)
inline.code.2 <- "`r[ #](.+)\\s*`\n"
knitr::knit_patterns$set(inline.code = inline.code.2)

knit2html("MyRmarkdownFile.rmd")
browseURL("MyRmarkdownFile.html")
```

Finding a general rule for this pattern that works for everyone seems impossible though.